# Preload stylesheets from node_modules in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, node-modules, stylesheet, preload

I installed Ionicons (npm install --save ionicons@4.6.3) in Angular 9 and imported them in my styles.scss file like so:

```
$ionicons-font-path: "~ionicons/dist/fonts";
@import "~ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons.scss";
```

Everything works fine, but looking at the lighthouse score, it slows down page load a lot. When I imported a google font in my index.html file, I did the following (preconnect and preload seem to do the same thing, both work):

```
<link rel="preconnect" as="font" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,600&display=swap"
    type="font/eot" crossorigin />
```

How do I do the same thing with a library imported from node_modules? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can move ionicons import path from style.scss to `angular.json` like below:

```
"styles": [ "
...,
./node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss/ionicons.scss",
...,
],
```

When angular serve or build application take care of the rest and load, optimize and minimize for you the scss. So you really don't need `rel=preload`.

Hope I help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem still persists. The load time even got worse from 7s to 9s.